# Luxon returns Invalid Interval when 'Interval.after' is called inside library

Tags: typescript, luxon

I am facing weird issue with Luxon when `Interval.after` method is called inside library.

```
const interval = Interval.after(dateTime, duration);
```

Following log is from the application `DateTime__Duration` and second line is logged result of `Interval.after` :

```
1535806800000__PT330M
[2018-09-01T16:00:00.000+03:00 – 2018-09-01T21:30:00.000+03:00)
```

However if I pass these values to library method and observe log there:

```
1535806800000__PT330M
Invalid Interval
```

Where reason is `invalid endpoints`. Calling `isValid` for `DateTime` and `Duration` returns true.

If I initialize `DateTime` and `Duration` exact same way that the application does, then `Interval.after` works inside the lib.

```
const interval2 = Interval.after(DateTime.fromISO('2018-09-01T16:00:00.000+03:00',
    {zone: 'Europe/Helsinki'}), Duration.fromObject({ minutes: 330 }));
```

Both calls are using same objects but `Interval.after` works only inside the application. Any idea what could cause this?

**UPDATE**

This seems to be related somehow to the `DateTime`. Could it behave differently in the app versus library even though luxon version is same? From what I've understood is that luxon doesn't have dependencies.

**UPDATE 2**

I managed to get reproducing version of this setup. Both app and lib sources can be downloaded from http://www.filedropper.com/luxon

For linking the lib locally into the app I used `yarn link` in the lib and `yarn link "luxon-test-lib"` in the app after that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this happening was due to locally linking the library while developing. Therefore even though both app and lib had same luxon version, they both had separate modules. That caused luxon library to break because of `instanceof` checks used there.

Comment: I believe this is now fixed in the latest version of Luxon, which no longer uses instanceof checks for this.

Comment: Yeah it should be fixed, I made a pull request and they continued from there